# How to style a link with Styled-Components?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, styled-components

I'm trying to learn Styled Components - It's great, and everything works awesome, but I can't get an `<a>` to be styled

This is my styled-component from StyledCSS.js:

```
...............
export const HeadLink = styled.a`
    color: pink,
    text-decoration: none,
`;
...............
```

Here is my react component

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    HeadCon,
    HeadLink,
    Container,
    Branding,
    Nav,
    UL,
    LI,
} from './StyledCSS';

function Header() {
    return (
        <HeadCon colorBG="#35424a">
            <Container>
                <Branding>
                    <h1>Acme Web Design</h1>
                </Branding>
                <Nav>
                    <UL>
                        <LI>
                            <HeadLink href="index.html">About</HeadLink>
                        </LI>
                        <LI>
                            <HeadLink href="index.html">Contact</HeadLink>
                        </LI>
                        <LI>
                            <HeadLink href="index.html">Weather</HeadLink>
                        </LI>
                    </UL>
                </Nav>
            </Container>
        </HeadCon>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be incorrect by any means. What isn't working? Can you be more specific? Is it possible to get a working codesandbox up that repros your issue? Here's a [test/demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/optimistic-montalcini-r0w9o?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark).

Comment: I was using a ```,``` instead of a ```;``` All is well

Comment: Aye, voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using semi-colons inside the `styled` object—not commas. Here is a working example.

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { HeadLink } from "./HeadLink";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <HeadLink href="index.html">About</HeadLink>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Headlinks.js**

```js
import styled from "styled-components";

export const HeadLink = styled.a`
  color: pink;
  text-decoration: none;
`;
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-frog-4yjvl?file=/src/HeadLink.js)